# Down arrow in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode9

Recently I started to notify a down arrow on the right side of files in the Project navigator. It seems that it appears for random files and there is no way for me to get rid of it (pulling the latest version from the repository, reopening the project etc.).

[image: Down arrow in the Project navigator]

PS. I found a way to get rid of it by restarting the Xcode, so I guess this is a bug.

Comment: Restarting Xcode worked for me. BTW: In Xcode 9.4 still not fixed.

Comment: Restarting Xcode worked for me too :) thanks @Sal

Comment: @rjobidon just restart Xcode, that should help.

Comment: bug still there in Xcode 11.4 and restarting worked for me

Comment: Git pull and restart Xcode worked for me.

Comment: Still seeing this behavior is Xcode 13.1